# How to get selected option within dom-repeat template in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I run into problem when trying to get the changed value from `<select>` elements within `<dom-repeat>` template ( Dart 1.17.1 + Polymer 1.0.0-rc.15 ). My code is as follows:

HTML, **shop.html**

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[shop.itemList]]">
    <div class="md-row">
    <div class="md-cell">[[item.name]]</div>
    <div class="md-cell"><input type="text" is="iron-input" name="quantity" bind-value="{{item.quantity}}" size="20" maxlength="20"></div>
    <div class="md-cell">
    <select name="size" selectedIndex="{{item.selected}}" value="{{item.itemSize}}" on-tap="changeSize" >
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</template>
```

Dart, **shop.dart**

```
@PolymerRegister('shop')
class Shop extends PolymerElement {

    @Property(notify: true)
    List<ShopItem> itemList = [];

    @reflectable
    changeSize(event, detail) {
        var model = new DomRepeatModel.fromEvent(event);

        print('Change Size');
        print(model.item.itemSize);
    }

    Shop.created() : super.created();

    ready() {
        set("itemList", [new ShopItem(name: "Milk"), new ShopItem(name: "Butter")]);
    }
}


class ShopItem extends JsProxy {
    @reflectable String id;
    @reflectable String name;
    @reflectable num quantity;

    String _itemSize = '2';

    @reflectable
    String get itemSize => _itemSize;

    void set itemSize(String s) {
        _itemSize = s;

        print("Changed Size " + _itemSize);
    }

    num _selected = 3;

    @reflectable
    num get selected => _selected;

    void set selected(num s) {
        _selected = s;

        print("Changed selected" + _selected.toString());
    }
}
```

When selecting `size` from the `<select>` element, the selected value does not update the model. So the call to `changeSize()` always gets the same value. Anyone has any advice on how to resolve this?

Comment: I guess array-selector https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates is what you are looking for. It's a while I used it myself therefore don't know details anymore but the link contains an example.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the problem is solved by adding `::change` to the `select` element as follows.

```
<select name="size" value="{{item.itemSize::change}}" on-tap="changeSize" >
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Apparently `::change` is needed to trigger the event that updates the model. And `selectedIndex` attribute is not needed for showing the default value.